# Inner loop condition during sparse table construction

Tags: algorithm

There are several implementations of sparse table where the condition for loop termination does not match the access within the loop, e.g. from [CP Algorithms](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/sparse-table.html#intuition)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= K; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j + (1 << i) <= N; j++)
        st[i][j] = f(st[i - 1][j], st[i - 1][j + (1 << (i - 1))]);
```

Why isn't the inner loop condition , `j + (1 << (i-1)) <= N` vs. `j + (1 << i) <= N`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the version with `j + (1 << (i-1)) <= N` performs unnecessary operations and, used with this particular loop body, may: access `st[i - 1][N]`; access a value that wasn't computed (e.g. `i = 4`, `j = N - 10` accesses `st[3][N - 2]` that wasn't written to earlier since `N - 2 + (1 << 2) > N`).

On the other hand, `j + (1 << i) <= N` computes an answer for every range that doesn't go out of bounds so it is sufficient.